# Is this sentence of "mixed construction"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

In English class, we've discussed the following sentence and considered if it is of mixed construction:

> The increase in the number of times his name appeared on such lists after the poem was published was enough to make him famous.

Is this sentence ok, or is it mixed construction?

Comment: I agree with JLG. I am assuming by "mixed construction" you mean *anacoluthon*, which it is not.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is an example of a mixed construction sentence. It is grammatically correct and is understandable. See [this link](http://www2.ivcc.edu/rambo/eng1001/eng1001_identifying_errors.htm) for some examples of mixed construction sentences.

It is, however, unnecessarily wordy. You didn't ask for this, but I would reword it something like:

*After the poem was published, his name began appearing on such lists often enough to make him famous*.